# Axios POST request

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, axios

I am trying to send some data from a form to a database using Axios. Here is the code:

```
const handleSubmit = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.post(
        ApiUrl,
        {
          batchId,
          name,
          description,
          source,
        },
        {
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
          },
        }
      );
      console.log(response.data);
      handleModal();
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error.response.data);
    }
  };
```

The error I get is this:

```
AxiosError {message: 'Request failed with status code 500', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_BAD_RESPONSE', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, …}
```

The values are being stored with useState. The database is receiving inputs but with no data.

I was investigating and I think I need to convert the JSON data to string, but I am not sure how to do that for my code.

Comment: Your post request code looks fine. See the answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73235123/axioserror-code-err-bad-response-config-transitional

Comment: There's not enough information here to even begin. What exactly is the response body (it should have been logged from `error.response.data`)? What do your server-side logs say about the error? Where do the payload variables come from and how are they assigned values? Does your server expect a JSON request payload and is able to parse it?

Comment: @BrendanOtherwhyz there is no answer on that question 

Comment: Sorry, yes your right. It's the comments that are relevant in this other question I think.

Answer (score 0):

If the database is receiving inputs but with no data, it sounds like the API endpoint is being hit properly but you are either improperly extracting the data from (`Express`?) or improperly passing the extracted values through to whatever function stores them in the database.

*You do not need to stringify your **axios.post** payload.*

If you're using `Express`, make sure you're properly extracting the data from `req.body` in your endpoint handler. If you're using `req.params` or `req.query` that would be a problem.

I would set up some `console.log('###')` markers in your backend code to ensure the data is reaching the query insertion point.

If you are still having issues, please provide more context regarding your backend logic and the trail between your API and the Database.

I hope this helps!